# Error in accessing all rubygem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

Whenever I'm trying to access a rubygem, i'm getting an error. E.g. with `rails -v` I get the following error:

```
/Users/sayanee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find railties (>= 0) amongst [bigdecimal-1.1.0, io-console-0.3, json-1.5.4, minitest-2.5.1, rake-0.9.2.2, rdoc-3.9.4] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/sayanee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/sayanee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /Users/sayanee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rails:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/sayanee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
    from /Users/sayanee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

I'm on MAC OSX Lion with the following configuration:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

rvm -v
rvm 1.16.6 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what was wrong thanks to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975973/gem-update-unable-to-convert-xe7-to-utf-8-in-conversion-from-ascii-8bit-to-u).

I had changed to [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/) and installed [oh my zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). So, I included the following in my file `~/.zshrc` to fix all the rubygem errors.

```
export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"
```

Comment: for Ubuntu use: ``export LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"``. This fixes rails generate errors on my system.