# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError "\xE7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, encoding, utf-8

I'm working on a rails API project.
Here is my code snippets

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Person.all
  end
end
```

and when I visit the url `localhost:3000/people.json`

> ```
> Encoding::UndefinedConversionError at /people.json
> "\xE7" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
> ```

I'm trying to solve this issue since last week, but still fighting with this.
I've found the bunch of similar question over stackoverflow such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975973/gem-update-unable-to-convert-xe7-to-utf-8-in-conversion-from-ascii-8bit-to-u) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428666/encodingundefinedconversionerror-xe4-from-ascii-8bit-to-utf-8) but non of the solution worked for me.

Here are the configuration I've.

**Rails 4.2.7.1**

**ruby-2.3.1**

**Operating system: macOS Sierra**

**Output of `locale`**

```
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**content on** `~/.bash_profile`

```
export LC_CTYPE="utf-8"
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
unset LC_ALL
```

**Output of** `Encoding.default_external`

```
 #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Comment: Where are you getting your input from? I would usually replace invalid characters (according to UTF-8) before saving it in the DB. If it's already in your DB: Did you save it as `String` or `JSON`?

Comment: I'm fetching it from MySQL, let me check the encoding of my database, Actually, I imported database from the old application and trying to use it in API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have had this problem a lot of times, so I usually try to get rid of any characters that are invalid to UTF-8 BEFORE saving it in the Database. If you have your record saved as a `String` you can replace invalid characters like so:

```
string = "This contains an invalid character \xE7"
string.encode('UTF-8', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
#=> "This contains an invalid character �"
```

This is ofc prior to converting it to a JSON object.

Comment: Is there any way to remove all of this character from the existing database?since I've imported content from another old database, and I do not want to encode every time.

Comment: You could write a data migration that goes through you data and performs exactly this action on each entry.

Comment: I found the problem. The problem was I've uuid field in the people table and it is binary type and has some wrong values. Thank you . You saved my day!

Comment: Glad I could help :)